# how to diagnose kernel NULL pointer dereference when I disconnect external monitor

Tags: kernel, external-monitor

This occassionally happens when I disconnect my usb-c external monitor (doubles as power supply).

journalctl:

```
Jul 17 09:52:07 noic11 kernel: usb 3-3: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jul 17 09:52:07 noic11 kernel: usb 3-3.2: USB disconnect, device number 4
Jul 17 09:52:07 noic11 systemd-udevd[42949]: 3-3:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper unbind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Jul 17 09:52:07 noic11 systemd-udevd[42949]: 3-3:1.0: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper unbind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3:1.0 0:0' failed with exit code 1.
Jul 17 09:52:07 noic11 systemd-udevd[42946]: 3-3.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper unbind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.2 189:259' failed with exit code 1.
Jul 17 09:52:07 noic11 systemd-udevd[42946]: 3-3.2: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper unbind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3/3-3.2 189:259' failed with exit code 1.
Jul 17 09:52:07 noic11 systemd-udevd[42946]: 3-3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper unbind snap_cups_cupsd /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3 189:257' failed with exit code 1.
Jul 17 09:52:07 noic11 systemd-udevd[42946]: 3-3: Process '/usr/lib/snapd/snap-device-helper unbind snap_cups_ippeveprinter /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-3 189:257' failed with exit code 1.
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: BUG: kernel NULL pointer dereference, address: 0000000000000390
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: #PF: supervisor write access in kernel mode
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: #PF: error_code(0x0002) - not-present page
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: PGD 0 P4D 0 
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: Oops: 0002 [#1] PREEMPT SMP NOPTI
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: CPU: 0 PID: 42506 Comm: kworker/0:0 Not tainted 5.19.0-46-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: Hardware name: LENOVO 21HMA003CD/21HMA003CD, BIOS N3XET38W (1.13 ) 04/26/2023
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: Workqueue: kacpi_notify acpi_os_execute_deferred
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: RIP: 0010:queue_work_on+0x22/0x70
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: Code: 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 41 89 fb 49 89 f2 49 89 d0 48 89 e5 53 9c 58 0f 1f 40 00 48 89 c3 fa 0f 1f 44 00 00 <f0> 49 0f ba 28 00 73 2f 45 31 c9 80 e7 02 74 06 fb 0f 1f 44 00 00
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb56a49d3fdf0 EFLAGS: 00010006
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: RAX: 0000000000000206 RBX: 0000000000000206 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000390 RSI: ffff9e1180051000 RDI: 0000000000002000
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: RBP: ffffb56a49d3fdf8 R08: 0000000000000390 R09: 0000000000000000
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: R10: ffff9e1180051000 R11: 0000000000002000 R12: 0000000000000004
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: R13: ffff9e18bf439f00 R14: ffff9e18bf439f25 R15: ffff9e18bf430c80
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9e18bf400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: CR2: 0000000000000390 CR3: 0000000117330000 CR4: 0000000000750ef0
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: PKRU: 55555554
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: Call Trace:
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  <TASK>
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  ucsi_connector_change+0x5c/0xa0 [typec_ucsi]
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  ucsi_acpi_notify+0x9a/0xb0 [ucsi_acpi]
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  acpi_ev_notify_dispatch+0x54/0x80
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  acpi_os_execute_deferred+0x17/0x40
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  process_one_work+0x21c/0x400
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  worker_thread+0x50/0x3f0
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  ? rescuer_thread+0x3a0/0x3a0
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  kthread+0xeb/0x120
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  ? kthread_complete_and_exit+0x20/0x20
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x30
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  </TASK>
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: Modules linked in: rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer snd_ctl_led snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp snd_soc_intel_hda_dsp_common snd_sof_probes snd_soc_hdac_hdmi snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd>
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  drm_display_helper iwlwifi crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec cec aesni_intel snd_hda_core crypto_simd snd_seq_midi mei_hdcp mei_pxp snd_hwdep thinkpad_acpi rc_core processor_thermal_device_pci snd_seq_midi_even>
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel:  crc32_pclmul psmouse nvme intel_lpss_pci thunderbolt i2c_i801 intel_lpss spi_intel_pci nvme_core spi_intel i2c_smbus idma64 xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas wmi i2c_hid_acpi i2c_hid hid video pinctrl_tigerlake
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: CR2: 0000000000000390
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: RIP: 0010:queue_work_on+0x22/0x70
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: Code: 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 44 00 00 55 41 89 fb 49 89 f2 49 89 d0 48 89 e5 53 9c 58 0f 1f 40 00 48 89 c3 fa 0f 1f 44 00 00 <f0> 49 0f ba 28 00 73 2f 45 31 c9 80 e7 02 74 06 fb 0f 1f 44 00 00
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: RSP: 0018:ffffb56a49d3fdf0 EFLAGS: 00010006
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: RAX: 0000000000000206 RBX: 0000000000000206 RCX: 0000000000000000
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: RDX: 0000000000000390 RSI: ffff9e1180051000 RDI: 0000000000002000
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: RBP: ffffb56a49d3fdf8 R08: 0000000000000390 R09: 0000000000000000
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: R10: ffff9e1180051000 R11: 0000000000002000 R12: 0000000000000004
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: R13: ffff9e18bf439f00 R14: ffff9e18bf439f25 R15: ffff9e18bf430c80
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff9e18bf400000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: CR2: 0000000000000390 CR3: 0000000117330000 CR4: 0000000000750ef0
Jul 17 09:52:10 noic11 kernel: PKRU: 55555554
```

uname:

```
Linux xxxxx 5.19.0-46-generic #47~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Jun 21 15:35:31 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```